# Help understanding the proof that $(C[0,1]), d_\infty$ is complete

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

So I was looking at a proof that shows that the metric space $(C[0,1],d_\infty)$ is complete.

I know that the definition of complete is that given a metric space X , every cauchy sequence in X converges to a point in X.

The proof was broken into 3 parts

1.create a candidate function and show that the sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ is cauchy and that the limit $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f_n(a)$ exists.

2.show f is continuous

3.show that $d_\infty(f_n,f)\rightarrow 0$

I understand why we do 1. It's so we can define a cauchy sequence which converges and 3. because we then show that it converges to a point in our space.
But I'm not totally sure why we need to show that f is continuous , could someone please explain ?

Comment: Every Cauchy sequences converges **to a point in $\mathbf X$**. You need to show that $f$ ,which is your candidate for the limit, is in $X$, so you need to show it is continuous.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг oh of course , because otherwise it wouldn't be a member of $C[0,1]$, right ?

Comment: Exactly. You can show that such $f$ exists, but if it were not continuous then it would not be in $X$, and you would not have shown completeness.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Thank you, it seems obvious now that you say it XD

Comment: You are welcome. For completeness, I will add an answer below,

Comment: For all $\epsilon\gt0$ there is $\delta\gt0$ such that $|f_n(x)-f_n(x_0)|\lt\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}$.

Since $f_n\to f$ uniformly in $[0,1]$ there is $n_0\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $n\gt n_0$ and all $x\in[0,1]$ we have $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\lt \dfrac{\epsilon}{3}$ and 
$|f_n(x_0)-f(x_0)|\lt \dfrac{\epsilon}{3}$.

Because of
$$f(x)-f(x_0)=f(x)-f_n(x)+f_n(x)-f_n(x_0)+f_n(x_0)-f(x_0)$$
it follows that $$|f(x)-f(x_0)|\le\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}+\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}+\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}=\epsilon$$
So $f$ is continuous in $x_0$ arbitrary in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for completeness you require that your candidate limit $f$ be in $X$. For this, you must show that it is continuous, for otherwise you cannot assert that the limit is in $X = \mathbf C[0,1]$. This is why the second step is important.